# This hook can only be used on a component that is a descendant of <Composer> react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, botframework

I am trying to use the `useScrollTo` hook from [Microsoft BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).

But I am getting the following error :-

```
This hook can only be used on a component that is a descendant of <Composer>
```

I am calling it inside a function component, which is in-turn being called under

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <-- the function component -->
  <React.StrictMode>
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the source code of `useScrollTo()` hook:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';

import ScrollPosition from '../types/ScrollPosition';
import useWebChatUIContext from './internal/useWebChatUIContext';

export default function useScrollTo(): (
  position: ScrollPosition,
  scrollToOptions: { behavior?: 'auto' | 'smooth' }
) => void {
  const { scrollToCallbacksRef } = useWebChatUIContext();

  return useCallback(
    (...args) => scrollToCallbacksRef.current.forEach(callback => callback(...args)),
    [scrollToCallbacksRef]
  );
}
```

And `useWebChatUIContext()` hook:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

import WebChatUIContext from './WebChatUIContext';

export default function useWebChatUIContext() {
  const context = useContext(WebChatUIContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('This hook can only be used on a component that is a descendant of <Composer>');
  }

  return context;
}
```

The error is thrown from the `useWebChatUIContext()` hook, `useScrollTo()` hook needs `scrollToCallbacksRef` from the `WebChatUIContext`, so you must use the `useScrollTo()` hook in a React function component and it must be a descendant component of the [`<Composer/>`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/3d091778933cbaf92b368e617430f38aa32866f4/packages/component/src/Composer.tsx#L282)

`<Composer/>` component render [`<ComposerCore/>`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/3d091778933cbaf92b368e617430f38aa32866f4/packages/component/src/Composer.tsx#L88), and `<ComposerCore/>` component render [`<WebChatUIContext.Provider/>`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/3d091778933cbaf92b368e617430f38aa32866f4/packages/component/src/Composer.tsx#L254).

Take a look at this [test case](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/3d091778933cbaf92b368e617430f38aa32866f4/__tests__/html/scrollToEndButton.persistWhileCallingUseScrollTo.html#L47):

```
const RunFunction = ({ fn }) => {
   fn();

   return false;
};

// ...
const renderWithFunction = fn =>
new Promise(resolve =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Composer directLine={directLine} scrollToEndButtonMiddleware={scrollToEndButtonMiddleware} store={store}>
      <BasicWebChat />
      <RunFunction fn={() => resolve(fn && fn())} key={Date.now() + ''} />
    </Composer>,
    document.getElementById('webchat')
  )
);

// ...
await renderWithFunction(() => useScrollTo()({ scrollTop: 300 }));
```

The `useScrollTo()` hook called in `RunFunction` component and it's a child component of `<Composer/>`